# WCF wsHttpBinding Certificate Security Negotiation Exception

Tags: c#, wcf, x509certificate, ca, wshttpbinding

So after having combed through MSDN, countless articles and even SO - I still have nothing to show for days of struggle.

So I have this: WCF service needs to be consumed by a client and I just keep hitting a SecurityNegotiationException

> Secure channel cannot be opened because security negotiation with the remote endpoint has failed. This may be due to absent or incorrectly specified EndpointIdentity in the EndpointAddress used to create the channel. Please verify the EndpointIdentity specified or implied by the EndpointAddress correctly identifies the remote endpoint.

I've seen this error all over the net and noone seems to have my exact scenario (with a feasible answer atleast).

My setup is local and not hosted by IIS (for time being) but hosted via Visual Studios 2010. My GenericIntegration (WCF service) makes use of wsHttpBinding (Message Mode) authenticated by certificates (I have a very custom username/password authentication + authorization class passed as a parameter by design) and there is no backing out of the security measures.

**Host's Config**

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="wsHttpEndpintBinding">
      <security mode ="Message">
        <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" establishSecurityContext="false" negotiateServiceCredential="false"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="wsHttpBehaviour" name="GenericIntegration.GenericService">
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpEndpintBinding" 
      name="wsHttpEndpoint" contract="GenericIntegration.GenInterface" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <!--<add baseAddress="http://localhost:59082/GenericService.svc" />-->
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="wsHttpBehaviour">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <serviceCredentials>
        <clientCertificate>
          <certificate findValue="GenIntegrationClient" storeName="My" storeLocation="LocalMachine" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
          <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust" />
        </clientCertificate>

        <serviceCertificate findValue="GenIntegrationClient" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="metadataBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>    

<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

**And the Client's config**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="endpointBehaviour">
                <clientCredentials>
                    <clientCertificate findValue="GenIntegrationClient" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My"
                        x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
                  <serviceCertificate>
                    <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust" revocationMode="NoCheck"/>
                  </serviceCertificate>
                </clientCredentials>
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="wsHttpEndpoint" maxBufferPoolSize="20000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000">
                <security mode="Message">
                    <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:59082/GenericService.svc"
            binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpEndpoint" behaviorConfiguration="endpointBehaviour"
            contract="GenService.GenInterface" name="wsHttpEndpoint">
            <identity>
                <certificate encodedValue="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" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Now about the certificates (and yes this is for testing only): GenIntegrationServer.cer has been created as a selfsigned CA root certificate with a private key to sign client certificates with. Both GenIntegrationServer and GenIntegrationClient certificates were generated with *makecert*. The client certificate is linked to the private key and is correctly installed in the personal store.

I am still quite new to certificates, private keys and secure comms - I simply cannot reason where I make my mistake. I didn't find too many posts about specifically using certificates in this manner.

Can anyone assist before I lose more hair or sleep over this?

**UPDATE**

As per request, I added the logging. But the most they reveal is:

```
<s:Body>
    <s:Fault>
        <s:Code>
            <s:Value>s:Sender</s:Value>
            <s:Subcode>
                <s:Value>a:InvalidSecurity</s:Value>
            </s:Subcode>
       </s:Code>
       <s:Reason>
           <s:Text xml:lang="en-ZA">An error occurred when verifying security for the message.</s:Text>
       </s:Reason>
    </s:Fault>
</s:Body>
```

Sadly, I still do not understand why security validation is failing. Any Ideas?

Comment: Configure the service client and host for verbose logging (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025(v=vs.110).aspx). This should give you a better idea of what's going wrong internally when the negotiation fails. Use this information to either solve the problem or ask a more specific question once you have more info.

Comment: Additionally a common problem I had with setup's like this is that the IIS service account doesn't have read permissions on the private key. Install the WSE3.0 tools then use the certificate tool to grant the private key permission.

Comment: Added the logging as per request. I'll edit my question with the the results.

Comment: Are you using the service log viewer tool to view the logs? There should be alot more information here.

Comment: I did use the trace log viewer but that didn't seem to be my problem (and yes it yielded alot more but none of which seemed relevant to me). Turns out my certificates weren't installed in the correct certificate store. Each party needed eachother's certificate installed in the Trusted People certificate store in addition to being installed in the Personal Store. I'll post a full solution later. Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out I needed to add the certificates to different stores.

In addition to already having the certificates set in the personal stores (as indicated by the config), I had to install the the server's certificate on the client and vice versa. I also had to make sure that the client contained the client certificate's personal key and the same with the server.

This does not sound too complete but I'll post a full article on how I did this.

Comment: if you found a solution to your own question, note that you are allowed to mark your own answer as the correct answer.